# Add tcpdump in yocto build (Beaglebone Black)

Tags: beagleboneblack, tcpdump, yocto, recipe

I want to add tcpdump into yocto build

I found that I need to add `meta-networking` into `bblayers.conf`. `meta-networking` is apart of `meta-openembedded`

Following are the steps I followed :

1. Downloaded complete `meta-openembedded` : `git clone git@github.com:openembedded/meta-openembedded.git`
2. Checked out to `jethro` branch and confirmed that `meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump_4.7.4.bb` is present
3. Added `meta-networking` and its dependent packages into `bblayers.conf`

BBLAYERS

```
/home/linux/work/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
/home/linux/work/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
/home/linux/work/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
```

4. Triggered full build and copied the images onto sdcard.

I am still unable to see tcpdump binary after booting up BBB(Beaglebone black). I am pretty sure I am missing something. I am new to yocto. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `tcpdump` to your image recipe. For a quick test, you add the following line to your `conf/local.conf`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tcpdump"
```

(Note the leading space in the assignment).
Just adding a layer won't add anything to your image.

Update:
In order to do do it correctly, you should add `tcpdump` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in your own image recipe. Eg.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "tcpdump"
```

If you don't have your own image, you could add a `<image-name>.bbappend` file to your own layer, with the line above.

Comment: Thanks. It works. To do it in a standard way, Can the same line be added to tcpdump_4.7.4.bb?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with instructions on how to do this long-term. Just an additional note, no, the tcpdump recipe can't add itself to any image; a recipe can't influence any other recipe.